# Boost Python "cannot open source file 'pyconfig.h'" when importing using "#include <boost\python.hpp>"

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I am attempting to use Boost Python for a project. I have downloaded and build version 1.70 on Windows 10, and I am using Visual Studio Code. When attempting to import boost into my c++ project with the line:

```
#include <boost\python.hpp>
```

, I receive the following error:

```
cannot open source file "pyconfig.h" (dependency of "boost\python.hpp")
```

I have looked into similar issues, and the primary solution I have found was to edit user-config.jam to include the location of my python installation. I have done so, and the line within user-config.jam looks like this:

```
using python : 3.7 : C:\Users\broke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37 ;
```

After adding this line, I rebuilt Boost Python. This did nothing to remedy the issue. I would greatly appreciate help on this matter. Thank you.

Comment: THANK YOU! I could not figure out what the error was telling me. FYI if you are using vscode add to the include path ${workspaceFolder}/**
/usr/include/python3.6m
<your_path_to_boost>/boost_1_80/boost_1_80_0 and the error goes away. Also holy cow I have no idea why boost is so weird getting these libs built....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to make sure the `python/include` folder is added to your includes. `C:\Python\Python37\include` for me on windows. You will also need to link the python library.